# Looking to replace class attribute in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to replace the background color of a textarea according to the time of day with information coming from moment.js. Each color depends on whether moment.js time is less than, equal or greater than the entry. This will be used in a day scheduler/calendar. I have two different codes I tried and neither works. I am new to coding, 6 weeks into a class.

```
    var correctTime = moment().hour();
    var time9 = 9;
    var time10 = 10;

    function rightColor() {
    if (correctTime > time9) {
        $("#box9").addClass("past");  
    }
    else if (correctTime >= time9 && correctTime < time10) {
        $("#box9").addClass("present");
        $("#box9").removeClass("past");
    }
    else (correctTime < time9); {
        $("#box9").addClass("future");
        $("#box9").removeClass("present");
        $("#box9").removeClass("past");
    }
}
```

Second approach using switch statement.

```
var correctTime = moment().hour();
    var time17 = 17;
    var time18 = 18;

    switch(time17) {
    case correctTime > time17:
        switchClass("box5").addClass("past");
        break;
    case correctTime >= time17 && correctTime < time18:
        switchClass("box5").addClass("present");
        break;
    case correctTime < time17:
        switchClass("box5").addClass("future");
        break;  
        default: 
    }
```

CSS portion.

```
  .past {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: black 2px 2px;
  }

  .present {
    background-color: #ff6961;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: black 2px 2px;
  }

  .future {
    background-color: #77dd77;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: black 2px 2px;
  }



 <tr>
            <div class = "col-md-2">
              <th scope="row" id="9amTime" class="timeOfDay">9:00am</th>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-8">
              <td class="event-box"><textarea class="text-box" value="" id="box9"></textarea></td>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-2">
              <td class="save-box"><button id="save9am" class="btn btn-outline-secondary saveBtn" type="button"><i
                class="far fa-save"></i></button></td>
            </div>
          </tr>
```

Comment: Hi Félix. Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the actual problem you are facing? Does the code not do what you expect, is there an error thrown?

Comment: Also, it would be useful to add the html element which you are trying to update.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. That is correct, none of the colors are showing up in the textarea. I will add the HTML to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the function call, in the sense that you either call the function early (i.e. before the page has loaded; since you are using jQuery, use the `document.ready` listener, or its shorthand form), or it's not called at all.

I have made this fiddle with the code you supplied, and after correcting a few minor problems, the code works:

https://jsfiddle.net/o9rhbn4k/

Note that there are some issues with your code:

```
   else (correctTime < time9); {
```

You are missing an `if`, and the `;` is not needed. That line should be:

```
else if (correctTime < time9) {
```

Anyway, have a look at the fiddle and change the value of the `correctTime` variable, and the background of the textarea will be updated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No worries, glad to help. Does it work in your context?

Comment: Not working yet. I tried changing the time to 12 in jsfiddle and didn't see the color change. Probably not using it correctly, new to jsfiddle too.

Comment: With the way you have structured your code, you would only see changes for 8, 9 and 10. Anything above 10 would set the grey background. 8 will be greed, 9 red, and everything above including 10, grey.

Comment: I tried it in fiddle and saw it changing between 8, 9, 10. So it does work, now I need to replicate it in my code. I turned off all other lines of code in my js so this is the only code running and still doesn't work. I know the js is working because I did a localStorage save right above this code and it worked. Got to keep searching.